# Creating UITabBarController in a UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

My app has a drawer menu view and some content views.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    // Side menu view controller
    UIViewController *menuViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"sidebar_menu"];
    UINavigationController *menuNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:menuViewController];
    // The initial content view controller
    UIViewController *contentViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"content1"];
    UINavigationController *contentNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:contentViewController];

    NVSlideMenuController *slideMenuController = [[NVSlideMenuController alloc] initWithMenuViewController:menuNav andContentViewController:contentNav];
    slideMenuController.slideDirection = NVSlideMenuControllerSlideFromRightToLeft;

    self.window.rootViewController = slideMenuController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

I want to insert a tab bar controller programatically to content view. I want the change the current content view to another content view  when the tab bar item button pressed.

Is it possible to create this kind of structure? How could I achieve this?

Comment: You `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` implementation lacks `return YES;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to code that you've just described in the question. Here is how you can modify your code to add `UITabBarController` that wraps your `contentViewController`, I've changed *The initial content view controller* section:

```
// The initial content view controller
UIViewController *contentViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"content1"];
[contentViewController setTabBarItem:[[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"My Content" image:[UIImage new] tag:1]];
UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
[tabBarController setViewControllers:@[contentViewController/* you can add more view controllers if needed*/]];
UINavigationController *contentNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tabBarController];
```